# Not able to access user information through Facebook api in c# on the same computer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

What's happening is say user A Logs in and provides the rights for the app to access his/her Data we extract his data then..

But what the problem is when another person Logs into his/her account using the same computer and grants permission we are getting the Data of User A and not B..

```
 if(Request.Params["code"] != null)
            {
                Facebook.FacebookAPI api = new Facebook.FacebookAPI(GetAccessToken());
                string me = api.Get("/me");
                string meFriends = api.Get("/me/friends/");
                   }
```

I am accessing the user info by the above code ..

What should we do about it?

Comment: `GetAccessToken()` - where/how are you actually storing the access token? In user data or local machine data?

Comment: I don't have a good explanation for why the user is getting the wrong data then. Can you debug the requests and figure out why: are you sending the same token for both users, the same cookie, or something else? (Same cookies ought not happen if they're logged into different accounts.)

Comment: Have found out a solution for the same =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known problem with the SDK saving the data into the session. I'm not 100% sure for C# but I guess it's the same as PHP. The SDK (in PHP ) checks if user's Signed Request is available in session:

```
  public function getSignedRequest() {
    if (!$this->signedRequest) {
      if (isset($_REQUEST['signed_request'])) {
        $this->signedRequest = $this->parseSignedRequest(
...
```

What I do is everytime I check the validity of the current user's access token. But someone mentioned that's not effective (although I tend to disagree:) ).

In short SDK doesn't check for validity and takes the data from session as first source. That's why 2nd user has the 1st user data.

Comment: That was exactly what my solution was :)